# Why does this error appear when building release build and causes crash but not with emulator or usb debug?

Tags: react-native

I am having an issue where the application that is build using `./gradlew bundleRelease` (aab) or `./gradlew assembleRelease` (apk). At the moment when user clicks the application it crashes straightaway and this issue doesn't happen on emulator when building the application using `npx react-native run-android` or using the real device through usb debugging.

In the google play developer console I got the following error that shows up

```js
FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
Process: com.vahingonsattuessa, PID: 18803
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:248)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:277)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1408)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1200(ReactInstanceManager.java:138)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

And

```js
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:248)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript (JSBundleLoader.java:29)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:277)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext (ReactInstanceManager.java:1408)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1200 (ReactInstanceManager.java:138)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run (ReactInstanceManager.java:1104)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
```

Any ideas why this happens and how would I be able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The same here. I don't know why. I already ammend the build.gradle adding

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    root: "../../",
    entryFile: "index.js",
    cliPath: "node_modules/haul/bin/cli.js",
    devDisabledInAppDev: true,
    devDisabledInAppTest: true,
    devDisabledInRelease: true,
    bundleInAppDev: true,
    bundleInAppTest: true,
    bundleInRelease: true,
]
```

But, didn't work yet. Even after this fix I'm getting the crash.
I keep going looking for the issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33323299)

Comment: The problem here was that then index.android.js kept disappering and had to be created with script and the clean up extra stuff it created in the icons etc.